# Loop through each row and write ID if it exists in list - pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'd like to create a new column called `'LT'` which contains the value from ID if that ID is present within the list `lt`:

dataframe converted to list:

```
ltlist = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Is a dataframe:

```
org = Dataframe({ID: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10})
for i, row in org.iterrows():
    blank = 0
    lt_val = org.at[i,'ID']
    if lt_val in ltlist:
        lt_val = org.ID
    org.at[i,'LT',] = lt_val
    else:
        blank
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can implement your `if` / `else` in a vectorised way using `numpy.where`:

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np

ltlist = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
org = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]})

ltlist_set = set(ltlist)
org['LT'] = np.where(org['ID'].isin(ltlist_set), org['ID'], 0)
```

We use `set` for O(1) lookup efficiency.

Comment: I'm getting an error: "TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'" here: ltlist_set = set(ltlist) - I think the issue is that org is a dataframe (although I must keep it as such as there is other data in the frame outside of the example)

Comment: @TimScongack, See update for full code - this works fine if you copy-paste exactly.

Comment: Also, I was planning on adding additional elifs in order to check other columns in the df, can I do that within the vectorized way?

Comment: @TimScongack, Yes, of course. But that would be [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Comment: if you're interested: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50205684/how-to-iterate-a-vectorized-if-else-statement-over-additional-columns

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd 

ltlist = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

org = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]})

LT_val = []
for i, elements in org.items():
     for element in elements:
        if element in ltlist:
             LT_val.append(element)

        else:
             LT_val.append('NaN')

org['LT'] = LT_val
print(org)
```

We can run a for loop that will iterate through each column and value within the column. Since you only have one column it will iterate through the id column and the elements in that column. I use the .items() method to get each element. IF the element is in the ltlist, we can append it to an empty list called LT_val. If the element is not in the ltlist we can append to LT_val a nan value using numpy's np.nan function. In the end we create a new column in the dataframe called 'LT' which will store each ID that is in the original list, and will create a NaN value for each ID that is not in the original list.

```
   ID   LT
0   1    1
1   2    2
2   3    3
3   4    4
4   5    5
5   6  NaN
6   7  NaN
7   8  NaN
8   9  NaN
9  10  NaN
```

Comment: ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index: org['LT'] = LT_val

Comment: Did you use the np.nan function to fill in the missing values? That should enable the index length to be a match since we are fillin in "NaN" for each ID that is not in the original list.      else:
                                                                                        LT_val.append('NaN')

Comment: The else statement is used in this scenario to add NaN values so that your index lengths line up with each other so that you avoid the ValueError in this situation.

Comment: I just checked again and it worked and got the output I've noted. Try one more time and it should work. The else statement that appends 'NaN' to the LT_val list should match the index lengths up. I'm currently getting 0 errors from the code, so I would attempt it one more time.