# How to iterate a vectorized if/else statement over additional columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np

ltlist = [1, 2]
org = {'ID': [1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], 'ID2': [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 2]}

ltlist_set = set(ltlist)
org['LT'] = np.where(org['ID'].isin(ltlist_set), org['ID'], 0)
```

I'll need to check the ID2 column and write the ID in, unless it already has an ID.

output

```
ID  ID2 LT
1   3   1
3   4   0
4   5   0
5   6   0
6   7   0
7   2   2
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1**

You can nest `numpy.where` statements:

```
org['LT'] = np.where(org['ID'].isin(ltlist_set), 1,
                     np.where(org['ID2'].isin(ltlist_set), 2, 0))
```

**Option 2**

Alternatively, you can use `pd.DataFrame.loc` sequentially:

```
org['LT'] = 0  # default value
org.loc[org['ID2'].isin(ltlist_set), 'LT'] = 2
org.loc[org['ID'].isin(ltlist_set), 'LT'] = 1
```

**Option 3**

A third option is to use `numpy.select`:

```
conditions = [org['ID'].isin(ltlist_set), org['ID2'].isin(ltlist_set)]
values = [1, 2]

org['LT'] = np.select(conditions, values, 0)  # 0 is default value
```