# Is it possible to create Pandas vectorization in this use case?

Tags: python, regex, pandas, string

I am trying to make a Pandas vectorization script that serves the same purpose as the `.apply` method below:

```
concised_df['email_account_letter_or_number_only'] = concised_df.apply(lambda x: x['email_account'] if (str(x['email_account']).isdigit() or not bool(re.search('[a-zA-Z]', str(x['email_account'])))) else (re.sub('[^A-Za-z]+', '', x['email_account'])), axis=1)
```

The logic of the code works as this: If `email_account` is all numbers or if it contains no letters, then just store `email_account` for `email_account_letter_or_number_only`. Else, perform `re.sub` to only keep letters (in other words, remove all numbers and special characters) for `email_account_letter_or_number_only`.

The reason I am trying to make Pandas vectorization is to make my method more optimized. As stated in this blog https://towardsdatascience.com/apply-function-to-pandas-dataframe-rows-76df74165ee4 (**Method 6. Vectorization**), Pandas vectorization is much faster than `.apply`.

Here's an example of the input and output I want:

| email_account | email_account_letter_or_number_only |
| --- | --- |
| 0018889 | 0018889 |
| nacho.taro | nachotaro |
| nachth45678 | nachth |
| nacikita | nacikita |
| nacia_art | naciaart |

I've tried Goole searching "Pandas vectorization with if else conditions", but the results I was able to find thus far all referenced other methods such `numpy.where` or `pd.DataFrame.loc` ([How to iterate a vectorized if/else statement over additional columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50205684/how-to-iterate-a-vectorized-if-else-statement-over-additional-columns)) instead of Pandas vectorization.

Comment: I know this is a follow up, but if you want someone to provide you the best solution, they need to understand your problem and the data you're working with, first. Start with providing 5-10 rows of your data as TEXT only (not images, please), with the expected output. Also explain what the code is trying to do. Code walks, data talks.

Comment: That makes sense, @cs95. I was about to follow up with the sample output table, but I saw either you or Nick has added the table to it. Thanks. I will add more description to my code now.

Comment: Ok, try `df['email_account_letter_or_number_only'] = np.where(df['email_account'].str.isdigit(), df['email_account'], df['email_account'].str.replace(r'[\W_]+', ''))` `np.where` is pretty vectorized.

Comment: @cs95 but it outputs `['0018889', 'nachotaro', 'nachth45678', 'nacikita', 'naciaart']`, as 'nachth45678' not matching`only keep letters (in other words, remove all numbers and special characters) for email_account_letter_or_number_only.`

Comment: np.where(df['email_account'].str.isdigit(), df['email_account'], df['email_account'].str.replace(r'[\W_\d]+', ''))

Comment: @Ferris yes that's right, thanks for the nit!

Comment: Thank you @cs95 and Ferris for editing. That works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
import io
import pandas as pd

df_str = '''
email_account   email_account_letter_or_number_only
0018889 0018889
nacho.taro  nachotaro
nachth45678 nachth
nacikita    nacikita
nacia_art   naciaart
'''
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(df_str.strip()), sep='\s+', index_col=False)



# 1.replace the char that is not letter or number to ''
obj = df['email_account'].fillna('').str.replace('\W|_', '')
# 0        0018889
# 1      nachotaro
# 2    nachth45678
# 3       nacikita
# 4       naciaart
# Name: email_account, dtype: object



# 2.replace the digit to '' when the cell contains letters, regexp
cond = obj.str.contains('\D')
obj[cond] = obj[cond].str.replace('\d', '')
print(obj)

# 0      0018889
# 1    nachotaro
# 2       nachth
# 3     nacikita
# 4     naciaart
# Name: email_account, dtype: object


# result
df['tag'] = obj
df['email_account_letter_or_number_only'] == df['tag']
# 0    True
# 1    True
# 2    True
# 3    True
# 4    True
# dtype: bool
```

You can also def a function to handle the data, and map or apply:

```
# def a function and apply, use pandas Series map
def data_clean(email):
    if pd.isna(email):
        return '' 
    else:
        email = re.sub('\W|_', '', email)
        if email.isdigit():
            pass
        else:
            email = re.sub('\d+', '', email)
        return email   


df['email_account'].map(data_clean) == df['tag']
```

I think this method is more effective than python native `for iteration`.

---

Add performance test:

```py
In [12]: import re
    ...: obj_r = df['email_account'].copy()
    ...: def fun1(obj_r):
    ...:     obj = obj_r.fillna('').str.replace('\W|_', '')
    ...:     cond = obj.str.contains('\D')
    ...:     obj[cond] = obj[cond].str.replace('\d', '')
    ...:     return obj
    ...:
    ...: def fun2(obj_r):
    ...:     obj = obj_r.map(data_clean)
    ...:     return obj
    ...:

In [13]: %timeit fun1(obj_r)
2.4 ms ± 197 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [14]: %timeit fun2(obj_r)
187 µs ± 7.56 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Comment: Great answer. How does the performance of this approach compare to the apply() approach?

Comment: This is a decent start but I think the selection of digit only rows is a bit brittle. Here `cond = obj.str.contains('\D')` should be run before the previous replace step, or you might include rows like "abc123_def" incorrectly.